# ATMEGA32 TQFP-44 PORTA Pin Order

Tags: atmega, layout, atmel

Is there a logical reason why all the ports of the ATMEGA32A TQFP-44 count anticlockwise from 0 to 7 in an anticlockwise direction round the chip except for PORTA that counts clockwise, that leaves any sensible layout of a prototype board with the pin headers reverenced for PORTA

[image]

I am attempting to get half reasonable results from the ADC so I have put 5v VCC separate 5v AVCC separate 2.5v reference and 1206 filter caps that I can try different values as close to the chip as pos on the reverse.

criticism welcome

Comment: Best guess: it made the chip design and pin termination easier for Atmel. Is your second statement related to this?

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer, why Atmel choose to do this particular pinout. I guess, that it was easier to bond - as engineers typically do not violate patterns without reason.

**For you second question:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQKTSK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the schematic I usually use for ATMEL-MCUs. Note, that it does not use a seperate VRef source. Usually, the internal reference is stable and precise enough.

Also, over the years, I made a library to allow for temperature compensation and offset/scale compensation of individual ADC-channels. Takes a bit of EEPROM and RAM but you have to use it anyways in a solid product. Therefore, I usually do not need an external VREF.

Furthermore, this device only has a 10 bit ADC - so VRef stability is not that big of an issue (we are talking 977 ppm).

The only advantage an external VREF can provide in such cases, is the fact, that you dont need to calibrate the product as initial accuracy tends to be better (0.1% device e.g.). But, you can also use the internal VREF, apply temperatur compensation as well as scale/offset compensation and put in three measurements with a multimeter - cheaper, more reliable, precise and stable enough.

**ALSO:** Much more important than the actual components is a solid ground layout.
Please make sure to have a solid ground fill below your MCU and analoge circuits with many vias (three or four) in parallel for each connection.

If you need to use an external reference, make sure it can handle capacitive loads!